# React js Cannot destructure property as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Quite new to React and I'm stuck in Cannot destructure property `id` of `props.contact` as it is undefined. I can't find what's wrong as props is already sent too.

[image: The error]

```
function App() {
  const namelist = [
    { id: "1", name: "sdsakas1", email: "wawesda1@gmail.com" },
    { id: "2", name: "sdsakas2", email: "wawesda2@gmail.com" },
    { id: "2", name: "sdsakas3", email: "wawesda3@gmail.com" },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <AddContact />
      <ContactList names={namelist} />
      <ContactCard />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
import React from "react";
import ContactCard from "./ContactCard";

const ContactList = (props) => {
  const renderContact = props.names.map((contact) => {
    return <ContactCard contact={contact} />;
  });

  return <div>{renderContact}</div>;
};
export default ContactList;
```

```
import React from "react";
import user from "../images/user.png";

const ContactCard = (props) => {
  const { id, name, email } = props.contact;
  return (
    <div className="contactlist-div">
      <hr />
      <div className="imgdiv">
        <img src={user} alt="" className="img1" />
      </div>
      <div className="list-div">
        <h3 className="h3">
          <span>
            {id}. {name}
          </span>
        </h3>
        <h4 className="h4">{email}</h4>
        <button className="btn-dlt">delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ContactCard;
```

```js
function App() {
  const namelist = [
    { id: "1", name: "sdsakas1", email: "wawesda1@gmail.com" },
    { id: "2", name: "sdsakas2", email: "wawesda2@gmail.com" },
    { id: "2", name: "sdsakas3", email: "wawesda3@gmail.com" },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ContactList names={namelist} />
    </div>
  );
}

const ContactList = (props) => {
  const renderContact = props.names.map((contact) => {
    return <ContactCard contact={contact} />;
  });

  return <div>{renderContact}</div>;
};

const ContactCard = (props) => {
  const { id, name, email } = props.contact;
  return (
    <div className="contactlist-div">
      <hr />
      <div className="list-div">
        <h3 className="h3">
          <span>
            {id}. {name}
          </span>
        </h3>
        <h4 className="h4">{email}</h4>
        <button className="btn-dlt">delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: `const { id, name, email } = props` ?

Comment: This is working for me. Added a minimal snippet of your code.

Comment: To do what @rustyBucketBay says you will need to spread the contact object. `<ContactCard {...contact} />`

Comment: Sorry guys, I was too fast. `This is a trap!!!` :D

Comment: It's working for me

Comment: Ok I changed it to const { id, name, email } = props; The error is gone but now the elements aren't showing up. The img and button is showing up but not the id, name and email elements.

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your App.js, do you need "CardContact" component? Is it same as "ContactCard"? If "CardContact" means "ContactCard" component, you already use it inside ContactList component.
2. If "CardContact" means "ContactCard" component and you still want to use it in App.js, you need to pass props "contact" into this component.

```
function App() {
  const namelist = [
    { id: "1", name: "sdsakas1", email: "wawesda1@gmail.com" },
    { id: "2", name: "sdsakas2", email: "wawesda2@gmail.com" },
    { id: "2", name: "sdsakas3", email: "wawesda3@gmail.com" },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <AddContact />
      <ContactList names={namelist} />
      {/*****  Do you need this CardContact? *****/}
      <CardContact />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yep those are the same. Sorry for the spelling mistake. The thing is, it works just fine without that component and I feel that this ContactCard component is extra. But I am new to this and was learning about destructure, copied exactly what the youtuber did and still ended up with an error.

Comment: you already use this component in ContactList component in 6th line,  "return <ContactCard contact={contact} />;"  I think maybe you don't need to use this component in App.js?

Comment: In App.js, if you want to use ContactCard component, you should pass one of element in namelist as props to it, for example "<ContactCard contact={namelist[0]} />", so that you can see a ContactCard of id 1.